# Error not getting propagated from called service to caller service

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, runtimeexception

We have 2 services which have REST controllers.

Caller Service calls like:

```
try {
            response = restTemplate.exchange(urlModifyAttributes, HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<>(attributesMap, headerMap), parameterizedTypeReference, uriVars);
            return response.getBody();
        } catch (RestClientResponseException e) {
            log.error("Modify attributes failed. Error {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Modify attributes failed. Error: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
```

While the called service throws a RuntimeException like:

```
throw new RuntimeException("Already modified");
```

But the caller service is not able to capture the error message "Already modified" using **e.getMessage()**. Rather e.getMessage() is returning something like "I/O error on PUT request for http....... " Is there a way by which I can capture the error message at the caller service level?

Both services are SpringBoot Applications and have RestControllers

Answer (score 1):

You are handling exception in caller service but in called service it need to send the exception as well. For generic u can refer this or have your own custom impl.

called service:

```
@Getmapping("/uri")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getIt(@RequestBody MyRequest req) {
try{
//...business logic

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

}catch(MyException e){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(e, HttpStatus.SOME_EXC_STATUS); //or custom exc
}catch(Exception e){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(e, HttpStatus.SOME_EXC_STATUS);
}
}
```

Then only you will be able to get exception status.

Answer (score 0):

The called service needs to send this in the response. You are making a rest call. Had it been a method, you could have caught it from caller too.

In the response entity of the called service pass the exception message. Either using controller advice or responsestatusexception.

Comment: "The called service needs to send this" What does "this" mean?

Comment: That means when you catch that exception in the called service. Throw it something like this.
throw new ResponseStatusException(400,
     "Already modified");
  }
So your called service will be able to read that message

Comment: Does not work. Still getting `I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost...: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost...; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost...`

Comment: Share little bit of called service